# Multiple non-restrictive modifiers in one sentence

Tags: commas, modifiers, non-restrictive

Consider the following sentence:

"I have not sent any further communication, since the email, to your office, so far."

Would both the phrases "since the email" and "to your office" be considered non-restrictive with respect to the main clause, so that there is no significant loss in meaning if they are deleted to interpret the sentence as follows:

"I have not sent any further communication so far."?

I believe this applies for single phrases with commas in a sentence, like:

"I have not sent any further communication, since the email, so far."

I wonder if it would apply in case of multiple phrases with commas as shown above, as well.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! I would suggest that you look up _clause_ first and reframe the question because it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have edited my question in cognizance of your kind feedback, user405662. Now I hope there is no confusion, as my concern here is not 'clauses'; rather, it's regarding the meaning of a sentence being affected by phrases demarcated by commas.